# i want to achive the formate of tooltip in chartjs

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdvfQ.png)

i want to show y axis formated  value (in specific color) a custom text with it in black text

[my approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAfi7.png)

soo far i managed to come to this point

this is my actual code using callbacks

```
 tooltip: {
                callbacks: {
                  title: function(tooltipItem) {
                    return tooltipItem.label;
                  },
                  afterTitle:function (tooltip){
                    return '_____________________________';
                  },
                  beforeBody:function (tooltip){
                    return 'wefsd';
                  },
                  labelTextColor: function(tooltipItem) {
                    return '#47C5FE';
                  },
                 
                  label: function(tooltipItem) {
                    return tooltipItem.formattedValue + '';
                  },
                  body:(tooltip)=>{return 'fsdfsd'}
                // footer:(tooltip)=>{return 'fsdfsd'}
                  
                },
                display:true,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                titleFontColor: '#0066ff',
                titleColor: '#999999',
                bodyColor: '#000000',
                displayColors: false,
                padding:10,
                cornerRadius:13,
                intersect:true,
                footerColor:'#000000'
                // enabled: false,
                // position: 'nearest',
                // external: (context) => this.externalTooltipHandler(context)
  }
```